# Image made using Illustrator aliased

Tags: adobe-illustrator

As you can see on the picture, there are some aliased edges (I mean the little circles and the black circles edges)even though this was made in Illustrator. How can I fix this. [image]

Please help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi and welcome. The question not clear enough. Maybe you mean aliazed? Obviously a png image will consist of pixels. Perhaps you mean the gray strokes?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I mean aliased. I'm editing now.